# Something like onStop() for Preferences / ListPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-asynctask, screen-rotation

I have a custom ListPreference that uses an AsyncTask and ProcessDialog. Works great, until I rotate my phone... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224676/android-view-not-attached-to-window-manager/6240320#6240320) is one possibility to solve this problem, but it requires access to onStop() which only Activities have, but not the ListPreference. So I am wondering: Is there something like this in the ListPreference / Preference class? How to detect Screen rotation from a Preference? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to deal with this will be to change the manifest for your PreferenceActivity subclass:

```
<activity android:name=".MyPrefs" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Preferences" />
```

This will prevent your activity from being recreated when you change the screen orientation as well as when the OSD keyboard appears.