# dismiss Progress Dialog in another Activity ... Android

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog

I have Tow Activities:

1. `FirstPageActivity`
2. `SecondPageActivity`

The App call the `SecondPageActivity` by the `FirstPageActivity`...
and the App send `HttpRequest` In the `SecondPageActivity`.

So I want to show Progress Dialog in the `FirstPageActivity` and After the `SecondPageActivity` Finish downloading the data, it Dismiss the Progress and then Appear.Is that Possible ?

Comment: why not showing the progress dialog in 2nd activity?!!

Comment: Actually The Customer doesn't want to show the progress in the second Activity Because it will be empty for a while, and that not so good :(

Answer (score 4):

> I want to show Progress Dialog in the FirstPageActivity and After the SecondPageActivity Finish downloading the data, it Dismiss the Progress and then Appear.Is that Possible ?

No.

You can't handle one `Activity's` UI functionality or any functionality from another `Activity.

If you start a `ProggressDailog` in `FirstPageActivity` then you must be dismiss it in `onPause()` before proceeding to other `Activity` as you said `SecondPageActivity`.

You can start a new `ProggressDailog` in `SecondPageActivity` from `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method.

**Update:**
From the document of [ProggressDailog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) you can see, to initialize a `ProggressDialog` its need to pass the current `Activity` context.

```
ProgressDialog(Context context)
ProgressDialog(Context context, int theme)
```

Comment: So if I want to do that, I should Download the data in the FirstPageActivity and then send it to SecondPageActivity...

Comment: Yeah, that will be a good way. Can I know what is the purpose of `SecondPageActivity`? If say the purpose then I can help you in more specific way.

Comment: yes, it will show the downloaded data from the http request, Actually I want to show the progress in the firstActivity because I don't want to show the progress bar on an empty activity until it finish download the data

Comment: are you downloading data in `FirstPageActivity` or in `SecondPageActivity`?

Comment: I will explain my problem again : I want the behind view of the progress dialog to be the firstPageActivity, and when the second Activity ready to appear "that mean that has been downloaded the data" so I will dismiss the progress and  show the second Activity. now I think this impossible if I download the data in the second Activity , and the only solution is to downloaded in the first Activity !!!! that's right ???

Answer (score 1):

```
and the App send HttpRequest In the SecondPageActivity.
```

As you say `SecondPageActivity` send `HttpRequest` , then best way is to show the `ProgressDialog` in `SecondPageActivity`.

In `onCreate` of `SecondPageActivity` show the `ProgressDialog` and dismiss it when `HttpRequest`  complete

Comment: Yes I agree with you,but Actually the Customer want to show the progress in the firstPageActivity, Instead of showing progress in the SecondActivity, because SecondActivity will be empty for a while :(

Comment: You can still show the `ProgressDialog` in `FirstActivity` and dismiss it after  `SecondPageActivity` is started

Comment: yes but then the second activity will be empty for a while, until it download the data ,,, yes ?

Comment: No. As I said show the dialog in onCreate of `secondActivity`

Comment: ok, but then the first activity will be disappeared and the background of the progress will be an empty activity because the data didn't download !!!!

Comment: You said the `secondActivity` is the one downloading the data, so I believe it will start download only after it is invoked by `FirstActivity`. When you start the Activity, immediately it will be on top of the stack

Comment: I will explain my problem again : I want the behind view of the progress dialog to be the firstPageActivity, and when the second Activity ready to appear "that mean that has been downloaded the data" so I will dismiss the progress and show the second Activity. now I think this is impossible if I download the data in the second Activity , and the only solution is to downloaded in the first Activity !!!! that's right ???

Comment: Yes, an `Activity` should be in Foreground to start a download request. It is better to do it in `FirstActivity` and then start the `SecondActivity`.