# How to toast a message unique to each swiping screen of the app in viewpager method?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Problem:  I am building an android application where I am using viewpager method to swipe the screens. 
I need to display the toast message with respect to each screen, for example "msg1" with screen 1, "msg2" with screen 2 and so on. But with my code as below, nothing is displayed: 
code:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[]{R.drawable.login_screen_1, R.drawable.login_screen_2};
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[]{R.drawable.login_screen_1, R.drawable.login_screen_2};

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = FaceBook.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
        // R.dimen.padding_medium);
        // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

---

### QUESTION 2

In my app, I am calling an async task on a button click and I am using onpreexecute method to start "progress dialog" and onpostexecute to end the same.

I am getting this error while implementing the above - "View not attached to window manager." Here is my async code -

```
 /**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class questionfeed_async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Hi "+userName+ "! Loading your question feed ");
        pDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
           pDialog.dismiss();
       }


    }
```

Comment: Where is your Toast?

Comment: Thanks for reply. actually I have not used Toast method as i dont know the condition where to use that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `Activity` or `Fragment` implement the [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface.

Define the `onPageSelected()` method like this:

```
@Override
public abstract void onPageSelected (int position){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"We are in page " + position, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And don't forget to call

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: I have posted one more question. it would be very helpful if you help me in that..?

Comment: is it a separate question ? post a link to it here

Comment: sorry i am unable to post the question right now. could you please help me here only. this might work

Comment: I request you to post a separate question, then send me a comment with a link, it will be easier for me that way :)

Comment: as you know the rules of SOF. i can only post another question after 3 hrs.  but its urgent for me.

Comment: ok sure ... ask we'll probably have to start the chatroom in a bit

Comment: the reason is this line of code: `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());`. Here you are holding a strong reference to the `Activity`, and a configuration change happens before the `AsyncTask` ends

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224676/android-view-not-attached-to-window-manager) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924825/view-not-attached-to-window-manager-crash) ... its the same problem with its solution

Comment: can you please tell me what is the meaning of mcontext in your that you provided with..??

Comment: `mContext` is an instance of the `Context` class. In your case it needs be a reference to the `Activity`, by passing `Activity.this`. The point is that you need to find another way to display a dialog. There are two methods in `AsyncTask` called `onProgressUpdate()` and `publishProgress` that you can try using ... just do some research and find a tutorial on it

Comment: i used both of the links that you suggested. but still then my problem is not solved. it would be very helpful if you suggest some links for me..!\

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I request you to post a separate question whenever you can and then add a comment here with the link ... I will be busy for the next hour or so, but I will be happy to help you when I am free :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit I am also facing this same issue here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789783/how-to-solve-the-error-view-not-attached-to-window-manager-in-android. It will be very helpful If you reply to that question.

Comment: @HiteshMatnani: will take a look at this question soon ... just add a comment here to remind me if I forget

Comment: Thanks that problem is solved. It will we great if you help me other problem where I am stuck

Comment: @ZygoteInit could please help me to solve this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793627/how-to-add-image-to-a-framelayout-in-android-app