# How to solve the error "View not attached to window manager" in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my app, I am calling an async task on a button click and I am using onpreexecute method to start "progress dialog" and onpostexecute to end the same.

I am getting this error while implementing the above - "View not attached to window manager."

Here is my async code -

```
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class questionfeed_async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Hi "+userName+ "! Loading your question feed ");
        pDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
           pDialog.dismiss();
       }
    }
```

I There are some solution given in SOF post question. try them too yet did not success.

Logcat -

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager at
> >     android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:670)
> >     at
> >     android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
> >     at
> >     android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:162)
> >     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:319) at
> >     android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302) at
> >     cheerz.fragment.Profile_Fragment$user_detail_async.onPostExecute(Profile_Fragment.java:207)
> >     at
> >     cheerz.fragment.Profile_Fragment$user_detail_async.onPostExecute(Profile_Fragment.java:149)
> >     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) at
> >     android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) at
> >     android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
> >     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
> >     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: pDialog is not part of your layout. Add it to your layout. Find it using the assigned id. then pass it to your async task through its constructor. then show/dismiss.

Comment: @Athena Thanks can you please help in telling how can I use constructor. I am new to this term

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
if (pDialog != null) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
   }
```

Insted of:

```
if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks I have try this also but it was giving same problem but I try something else that work

Comment: I have added progressBar in my XML and write it basic code to to start and stop.