# Android- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, exception

I already have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224676/android-view-not-attached-to-window-manager). But couldn't figure out what's the issue. 
I am sending an email in background using `BackgroundMail` in my `ImageSyncReciever` class. But when email is sent my app crashes while giving me the below error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament, PID: 7480
>                                                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{300e55de V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
>                                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:434)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:353)
>                                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:382)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:365)
>                                                                                                  at com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundMail.java:302)
>                                                                                                  at com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundMail.java:265)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5660)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)

Below is my code in which I am sending the email

```
     if (response.body().getStatus().equals("OK")) {

                            snapManager.updateSnapStatus(AssetsManagementContract.SnapEntry.COLUMN_SITE_SNAP, snap.getSnapName(), Constants.SNAP_SYNCED);
                            Intent broadcastSyc = new Intent();
                            broadcastSyc.setAction(Common.GetSyncImageAction());
                            broadcastSyc.putExtra("STATUS", true);
                            mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastSyc);
                            sendImage(mContext);
                            BackgroundMail.newBuilder(mContext)
                                    .withUsername("gmail id")
                                    .withPassword("pass")
                                    .withMailto("gmail id")
                                    .withType(BackgroundMail.TYPE_PLAIN)
                                    .withSubject("New Meter Installation")
                                    .withBody("Meter #" + msn + " is "+ com+ " and "+ status)
                                    .send();

                        }
```

How can i resolve this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated

**Note:** The email is sent when the form is submitted and after saving I am not using any dialog.

**Update 1**
Below is the `BackgroudMailer` class function

```
public class SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public SendEmailTask() { //error onPostExecute(BackgroundMail.java:265)
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(BackgroundMail.this.processVisibility) {
            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BackgroundMail.this.mContext);
            this.progressDialog.setMessage(BackgroundMail.this.sendingMessage);
            this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.progressDialog.show();
        }

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            GmailSender sender = new GmailSender(BackgroundMail.this.username, BackgroundMail.this.password);
            if(!BackgroundMail.this.attachments.isEmpty()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < BackgroundMail.this.attachments.size(); ++i) {
                    if(!((String)BackgroundMail.this.attachments.get(i)).isEmpty()) {
                        sender.addAttachment((String)BackgroundMail.this.attachments.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            sender.sendMail(BackgroundMail.this.subject, BackgroundMail.this.body, BackgroundMail.this.username, BackgroundMail.this.mailto, BackgroundMail.this.type);
        } catch (Exception var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
            return Boolean.valueOf(false);
        }

        return Boolean.valueOf(true);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(BackgroundMail.this.processVisibility) {
            this.progressDialog.dismiss(); // error onPostExecute(BackgroundMail.java:302)
            if(result.booleanValue()) {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BackgroundMail.this.sendingMessageSuccess)) {
                    Toast.makeText(BackgroundMail.this.mContext, BackgroundMail.this.sendingMessageSuccess, 0).show();
                }

                if(BackgroundMail.this.onSuccessCallback != null) {
                    BackgroundMail.this.onSuccessCallback.onSuccess();
                }
            } else {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BackgroundMail.this.sendingMessageError)) {
                    Toast.makeText(BackgroundMail.this.mContext, BackgroundMail.this.sendingMessageError, 0).show();
                }

                if(BackgroundMail.this.onFailCallback != null) {
                    BackgroundMail.this.onFailCallback.onFail();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is I cannot edit it as the file is locked.

Comment: You seem to dismiss a dialog in the SendEmailTask and since it is asynchronous this can lead to this error if that Activity is already finished for example. You may want to post that code here if you need more detailed help.

Comment: what's on line 302 in BackgroundMail.java ?

Comment: your stacktrace says that you call dialog dismiss here: `android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:365) at com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundMail.java:302)` that is the interesting code that you should include in the question

Comment: @R.Haq I have added the piece of cod for `302` and `265` error, also I can't edit it as it is locked.

Comment: @donfuxx I have updated my question can you please see it ?

Comment: i think this thread may be of a great help to you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager

Comment: @R.Haq I have already seen this, but the problem is I can't edit it as the file is locked :(

Answer (score 1):

in onPostExecute you dismiss the dialog without checking if it is actually shown:

```
this.progressDialog.dismiss();
```

add a check of isShowing for that (and a null-check just in case..)

```
if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) { 
   progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Also I see that you use static references to contexts. That can [lead to memory leaks](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2015/07/14/why-static-references-to-application-contexts-are-probably-not-the-best-idea/), but that is just a side note.

Comment: I can't edit any piece of code as the file is locked :(

Comment: That is unfortunate.. I suggest you find the developer who locked the file to unlock it for you.

Comment: I am using the external library, downloaded from `compile 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'`

Comment: Contact the developer of that library and report the issue or switch to another library or develop your own email sender. Or last not least since it is an open source project from github: fork it and fix it ;-)

Comment: Where have you find it? as this package was also on the github

Comment: So you are saying I should create separate files (same like in the library) and then add them into my project ?

Comment: It is up to you. Either contact third party developers and hope they fix it or do it yourself.